# Synchronize variable between router in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'd like to change value of a variable in a `router-view` by changing other variable in different `routre-view` synchronously. I wrote code like below to change variable `isFoo` in header and catch it in side bar, but it fails.

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <v-app id="app">
    <router-view name="sidebar"></router-view>
    <router-view name="header"></router-view>
    <router-view name="main"></router-view>
    <router-view name="footer"></router-view>
  </v-app>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  isFoo: false
}
</script>
```

and Sidebar.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="sidebar" :isOpen="isFoo"></div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'sidebar',
    data () {
      return {isFoo: this.$parent.$options.isFoo}
    }
  }
</script>
```

Header.vue:

```
<template>
  <button v-on:click="foo()">Button</button>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'header',
  methods: {
    foo: () => {
      this.$parent.$options.isFoo = !this.$parent.$options.isFoo
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is essentially about how to share state across multiple components of your app, and is quite general.

Your code does not work because you have copied `isFoo` across your components instead of just referencing a single source of truth for that data. Also you should specify reactive data in the `data` property of each component, not directly within the `$options` of the component.

I've fixed your code to make it work:

```js
const Header = {
  template: '<button @click="$parent.isFoo = true">Click Me</button>'
}

const Sidebar = {
  template: '<div>Sidebar: {{ $parent.isFoo }}</div>'
}

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      components: {
        header: Header,
        sidebar: Sidebar
      }
    }
  ]
})

new Vue({
  router,
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    isFoo: false
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/vuejs/vue/dev/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/vuejs/vue-router/dev/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <router-view name="header"></router-view>
  <router-view name="sidebar"></router-view>
</div>
```

**However** I do not recommend this approach. You really shouldn't be accessing `this.$parent` because it tightly couples the components.

I'm not going to go into detail about better ways of doing this because there are [lots of SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vuejs+share+data) which cover this topic.